# Different results from BeautifulSoup each time

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm doing a web scrape of a website with 122 different pages with 10 entries per page. The code breaks on random pages, on random entries each time it is ran. I can run the code on a url one time and it works while other times it does not.

```
def get_soup(url):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
    return soup

def from_soup(soup, myCellsList):
    cellsList = soup.find_all('li', {'class' : 'product clearfix'})
    for i in range (len(cellsList)): 
        ottdDict = {} 
        ottdDict['Name'] = cellsList[i].h3.text.strip()
```

This is only a piece of my code, but this is where the error is occurring. The problem is that when I use this code, the h3 tag is not always appearing in each item in the cellsList. This results in a NoneType error when the last line of the code is ran. However, the h3 tag is always there in the HTML when I inspect the webpage.

[cellsList vs html 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8eyT.png)

[same comparison made from subsequent soup request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJEey.png)

What could be causing these differences and how can I avoid this problem? I was able to run the code successfully for a time, and it seems to have all of a sudden stopped working. The code is able to scrape some pages without problem but it randomly does not register the h3 tags on random entries on random pages.

Comment: Page 1 of the site being scraped can be found at https://www.atcc.org/Products/Cells_and_Microorganisms/Cell_Lines/Human/Alphanumeric.aspx?.

Comment: Did you try with `lxml` parser?

Comment: Yes, the problem still persists even with the lxml parser.

Comment: This could be due to dynamically generated content. Consider using selenium to extract the html source.

Comment: What other info are you trying to get?

Comment: I am trying to get generic name, atcc name, organism, tissue, cell type, and disease.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are slight discrepancies in the  html for various elements as you progress through the site pages, the best way to get the name is actually to select the outer div and extract the text from the anchor.

This will get all the info from each product and put it into dicts where the keys are *'Tissue', 'Cell'* etc.. and the values are the relating descriptionm:

```
import requests

from time import sleep


def from_soup(url):
    with requests.Session() as s:
        s.headers.update({
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.82 Safari/537.36"})
    # id for next oage anchor.
    id_ = "#layoutcontent_2_middlecontent_0_threecolumncontent_0_content_ctl00_rptCenterColumn_dcpCenterColumn_0_ctl00_0_productRecords_0_bottomPaging_0_liNextPage_0"

    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(url).content)
    for li in soup.select("ul.product-list li.product.clearfix"):
        name = li.select_one("div.product-header.clearfix a").text.strip()
        d = {"name": name}
        for div in li.select("div.search-item"):
            k = div.strong.text
            d[k.rstrip(":")] = " ".join(div.text.replace(k, "", 1).split())
        yield d

    # get anchor for next page and loop until no longer there.
    nxt = soup.select_one(id_)

    # loop until mo more next page.
    while nxt:
        # sleep between requests
        sleep(.5)
        resp = s.get(nxt.a["href"])
        soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content)
        for li in soup.select("ul.product-list li.product.clearfix"):
            name = li.select_one("div.product-header.clearfix a").text.strip()
            d = {"name": name}
            for div in li.select("div.search-item"):
                k = div.strong.text
                d[k.rstrip(":")] = " ".join(div.text.replace(k,"",1).split())
            yield d
```

After running:

```
for ind, h in enumerate(from_soup(
        "https://www.lgcstandards-atcc.org/Products/Cells_and_Microorganisms/Cell_Lines/Human/Alphanumeric.aspx?geo_country=gb")):
    print(ind, h)
```

You will see 1211 dicts with all the data.

Comment: Thank you so much. This looks really close to what I need. It appears that something is off with the key 'cell'. The key should be 'cell type' with value 'epithelial' for example. Everything else looks great! Can you tell me where the 'u's are coming from?

Comment: Yes, the split was splitting up the key, I changed the logic to pull the key from the strong child and remove it from  the values using str.replace. The u  means it is a unicode string, it is nothing to worry about and if using python3 you would not see it at all

Comment: I finally had a chance to run your code. Unfortunately, I'm getting a 'NoneType' object not calable error on line 15.

Comment: Line 15 is the line:

    name = li.select_one("div.product-header.clearfix a").text.strip()

Comment: I think I have figured out why the code wasn't working. Thanks for all the help!